# Is there a misnomer about using the greeting "Chodesh Tov" on erev Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, social-convention

Is there something improper with saying "Chodesh Tov" on erev Rosh Chodesh or should one only use the greeting "Erev Tov" instead?

The reason I ask is that I've noticed historically whenever I say "Chodesh Tov" to people on erev Rosh Chodesh I seem to mostly get the greeting back "Erev Tov". So unless it is officially Rosh Chodesh is it improper/wrong to use that greeting until the day actually begins?

Also would it be improper to say "Chodesh Tov" several days after Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: This is probably just confused outcomes from the confusion concerning saying gut shabbos on Friday. For the record, many people I know from Europe start wishing people gut chodesh from erev shabbos of shabbos mivarchim hachodesh.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no real halachot regarding when to say the greeting or if you need to say it at all. Also, while the word "Chodesh" tends to be synonymous with ROSH Hodesh, so it is usually said at the beginning of the month (or, if you go by date, it could be the end of the month, too when there's a 30-day month), the meaning of the word "chodesh" means just "month". So, while a bit odd, there would be nothing wrong for someone to wish you "gut chodesh" on ANY day of the month, and each day, for that matter. It's like saying, "I hope the rest of your month is good."

Comment: @user6591 I had not heard of the minhag that you mention. I have heard of people saying "Good Shabbes" beginning from Wednesday, but there's a different reason for that being absolutely legit.

Comment: There may be something to the greeting making sense around Mincha time before Rosh Hodesh. Consider that Tachanun is omitted at Mincha prior to Rosh Hodesh. It seems that part of the *simcha* of Rosh Hodesh carries "backwards".

Comment: I made the greeting "Chodesh Tov" to several people just before Minchah/Maariv last night while I received back "Erev Tov" from people wiser than I. (I did get some "Chodesh Tov" greetings back as well but maybe out of politeness or not knowing this possible misnomer)